# Upgrade from 17.10 won't initiate

Tags: upgrade

I am currently using 17.10 and when prompted to upgrade I clicked on Upgrade, entered password authentication and nothing happened.

Tried several times, restarted etc. Still no upgrade.

There is no output of `sudo apt-get update` as was freshly updated. 
Below is the output of `sudo apt-get upgrade` .

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  caja-common libmarco-private1 libmate-desktop-2-17 libmate-menu2
  libmate-slab0 libmate-window-settings1 libmatekbd-common libmatekbd4
  libmatemixer-common libmatemixer0 libnih-dbus1 libqpdf18
  linux-headers-4.13.0-19 linux-headers-4.13.0-19-generic
  linux-image-4.10.0-42-generic linux-image-4.13.0-19-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.10.0-42-generic linux-image-extra-4.13.0-19-generic
  marco-common mate-control-center-common mate-desktop mate-desktop-common
  mate-icon-theme mate-menus mate-settings-daemon mate-settings-daemon-common
  mate-user-guide python-mate-menu
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  python3-update-manager update-manager update-manager-core
3 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 0 B/591 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4,096 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

I did not entered "yes" as I'd rather upgrade all at once.

Comment: "Doesn't work" doesn't exactly give us a problem to solve. So, we need a bit more, like an error or something, to find out WHY it doesn't work. Open a terminal and try it there. Start with `sudo apt-get update`, then run `sudo apt-get upgrade`. If you encounter errors at some point, post the error(s).

Comment: Hi. There was nothing else to say than "Nothing happens" because this is the case. The upgrade prompt box does not appear and that's it. There is no error message. Above is the output from terminal as asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Good news. I finally accepted the upgrade proposed following the sudo apt-get upgrade and now, when I run the update manager and click on "Upgrade" button the dialogue box appears.

Problem is thus solved. Thank-you Neobie for your collaboration and input.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you only know the GUI upgrade manager, I understand, why there is not much to say. Personally, I've made the experience, that there seems to be a problem with the GUI upgrade manager. I've seen it to be in the task panel but never open. Also it's holding back on errors.

For the future (and for other people stuck with upgrades not working), here are a few general hints:

If the you can see the upgrade manager in your task panel and it doesn't open upon clicking on it, you might want to kill the process and start it again. You can do so by either using the system monitor in GUI (processes tab) or in terminal the ps command along with grep to search for the process ID and the kill command to kill it.

In general, it is always a good idea, if an upgrade doesn't work, to go back to the terminal and run it there. (This by the way holds true for other applications that don't work too). This will give you error messages. Also, I've made the experience, that Ubuntu needs a mix of terminal upgrades and GUI upgrades in order to work. And if it doesn't work, there are a few things you can do.

Take a look at your output, below the list of packages. It says, "use sudo apt autoremove". This is actually a very common message that appears now and again. At this point upgrades sometimes get stuck. So, this very likely would have done the trick and is exactly why you try it in the terminal.

Therefore, if upgrades don't work, instead of playing around, I just started cleaning everything before performing the upgrade. I do this by use of a chain of commands. Looks like this:

```
sudo su
apt-get autoremove && apt-get remove && apt-get clean && apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

(Although, apt-get remove doesn't seem to do much these days? Not sure to be honest. But it works.)

With use of sudo su you become admin (root user). With the command `exit` you get out of it, when you are done.

Also sometimes Ubuntu gets stuck with some package during an upgrade. In this case an option is to try `sudo apt-get install -f`, which is going to attempt to fix broken upgrades.

And finally, if nothing goes, another try is dpkg or to be precise, the command `sudo dpkg --configure -a`.

These commands come in handy every now and then to get stuck upgrades and packages going.

HINT: you should aways make sure your internet connection is up and working before trying of them, including the upgrades. Just for example: often internet connections use the modem as DNS server, which could work for a while and suddenly it stops working. Leaving people connected to the internet but not being able to resolve any addresses. So, that's another one you might want to watch. In this case an upgrade won't work either.

Also, if the lifetime of a version has ended and it's not supported anymore, Ubuntu now deletes repos. In this case you get stuck all together. You can't perform any upgrades or even installations whatsoever. In this case you would have to edit your sources list (/etc/apt/sources.lst) and move on to a newer and avaiable version. Helpful in this case is changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release for the switch of the release names, as well a as Google search for currently supported versions ;)  After editing your sources list (as admin/root), you would perform a (sudo apt) update and dist-upgrade to move on to the according newer version.

BTW: in the past weeks, 2 times I had the upgrade process downloading broken packages and throwing an error during the upgrades. In the according cases it took a while until it worked again. In this case I tried it a day or a few later.